# Does `Pin` have a purpose not involving unsafe code?

Tags: rust

Is `Pin` just a semantic guarantee that's intended to be relied upon solely by `unsafe` code, at the end of the call stack? Is there any completely safe<sup>1</sup> Rust construct or API that would not work/compile without a pinned value? (besides calling a function that requires a `Pin<T>` obviously)

I think I understand how Pin "works" (it's not like it really does anything) and what it represents. I'm just wondering if the guarantee offered by this newtype is useful for anything other than ultimately having a stable raw pointer somewhere in `unsafe` code down the call stack.

<sup>1</sup> "safe" as in "not `unsafe`", I'm not implying that `unsafe` code in the standard lib is actually unsafe/unsound

Comment: Generators (and async implemented on top of them), since they're essentially self-referencing when the compiler generates the code for you.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman do they really use the `Pin` type under the hood (or have any kind of langage-level dependency on it)? Coroutine (async fn or generators) compilations looks to me like an opaque implementation detail that has nothing to do with the Pin structure but I could be wrong.

Comment: `Future::poll()` takes `Pin<&mut Self>`, so yeah, they do have a dependency on it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Oh you're right! I completely forgot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following totally safe (if you don't look into `Box` and `String`) code contains a self-reference:

```rust
use std::{future::Future, task::Context};
use futures::{future::pending, task::noop_waker_ref};

fn main() {
    let mut future = Box::pin(async {
        let x = String::from("hello");
        let y = x.as_str();
        pending::<()>().await;
        println!("{y}");
    });
    
    // Poll `future` once so it is suspended at the await point
    let mut dummy_ctx = Context::from_waker(noop_waker_ref());
    let _ = future.as_mut().poll(&mut dummy_ctx);
    
    // `future` now contains a self-reference
}
```

`async` blocks containing variables which borrow other variables produce `Future`s that contain self-references, and they are not defined using `unsafe` code.

Of course that may be an unsatisfactory example, since while the usage is not `unsafe`, it's also not safe code that's explicitly using an already existing `Pin` — the access to the contents of the pinned future is hidden in the compiler's transformation of your code.

---

In principle, you could define a type which makes use of its own *address*, such as by using it as a key in some table. In this situation, the `Pin` guarantee would ensure that the address never changes until the value is `Drop`ped, which is just what you want in order to have a stable key until it's time to remove the value.

This is essentially a weird case of self-reference, since it's making use of pointers to itself, but not by actually *dereferencing* those pointers, so it can be done in entirely safe code.

But, this is not really a practical reason to use `Pin`. You can usually conveniently obtain unique IDs by using an `AtomicU64` global counter (no deallocation is needed since it's infeasible to overflow before your program stops running), which can be done entirely internally to your type without needing the owner to follow the `Pin` rules.

In order to benefit from `Pin` rules for using addresses as IDs, you'd need to be doing something even more specific, like wanting the [structurally pinned](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html#projections-and-structural-pinning) members of a `struct` to be able to get IDs which are always in ascending order matching the field ordering.

In that case, `Pin` provides the same benefit as it does to composed futures: each element gets the guarantee of a stable address without having to create its own heap allocation. (Without composition, you might as well create a stable address by heap allocating your contents — this is what [`ouroboros`](https://docs.rs/ouroboros/) does to enable self-reference *without* `Pin`.)

Comment: I didn't expect an answer to dig that deep, thanks a lot for taking the time to write this. So my initial though was pretty much confirmed: Pin is pretty much only useful for unsafe code (and I'm not undermining this in any way, I love the concept of using the type system to pass around compile-time semantic information). The example about creating unique IDs is really creative though (of course I doubt anyone would actually use this in practice).

Answer (score 1):

Both [the standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html) and [this Cloudflare blog post](https://blog.cloudflare.com/pin-and-unpin-in-rust/) explain that `Pin` exists for self-referential structs (although they don't exclude its utility for other purposes, they don't mention any).

Technically self-referential structs cannot be written in entirely safe code, so some use of `unsafe` is required.  However, `Pin` exists because without it, there is no way to safely use self-referential structs in safe code, since the compiler can and does move values around in some cases.  Thus, the goal is to limit potential unsafe behaviour to `unsafe` blocks and not let the compiler introduce it on its own behalf by moving the value, which would be considered a bug in the compiler.